# Xampp phpmyadmin stopped working with specific error, and cant connect to Apache

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried some things to fix it, I changed the ports and I changed in a config file, skip-grant-tables.
But none of them worked, I don't want to use the backup folder bc the files in there are just too old. I will put a picture here of the error I keep getting.[This is the error I keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGkNg.png)

I hope someone can fix this with me, thanks!

Comment: So as that looks like a clean startup of mariaDB, I guess your issue is else where

Comment: _Small Note_ phpMyAdmin is a tool written in PHP that runs like a website to assist in the maintenance of a MySQL/mariaDB database. It is not a DBMS itslef

Comment: I am guessing that the issue is that Apache is not starting! Am I right?

Comment: In Xampp Apache starts without a problem, only Mysql won't start for some reason. I don't know what "MariaDB" is so I will research that! Already thank you very much!

Comment: Hey @RiggsFolly, I looked trough the config file, and I saw that I don't have "D:/Programme/Xampp/mysql/mysql.sock/"  That mysql.sock file does not exist in my orders. has that anything to do with the error I keep getting?

Comment: Itt does not use Unix Sockets in Windows

Comment: It looks, as RiggsFolly already stated, like your MariaDB is starting correctly. The picture you've pasted doesn't look to me to have any error in it. What makes you think it isn't running? Can you see it in the process list? What is the status on the XAMPP control panel/status page?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch hey! Because in Xampp when I try to start MySQL it gives this error in Xampp : Error: MySQL terminated unexpectedly
20:04:04 [mysql] Cause could be a blocked port, missing dependencies,
20:04:04 [mysql] missing permissions, a crash or the termination of another method.
20:04:04 [mysql] Press the Logs button to see and check error logs
20:04:04 [mysql] in the Windows Event Viewer for further information
20:04:04 [mysql] If you need further help, copy the entire contents of the log window
20:04:04 [mysql] and add it as a supplement in a new forum entry.

Comment: Do you have a different MySQL server installed? Perhaps at one point you installed MySQL yourself, and now are installing it as part of the XAMPP package? Check your process list to see if there's anything related to MySQL or MariaDB that's running, or if anything is listening on port 3306. Also you could check the logs as listed in the error message again because the image you posted doesn't show any failure or errors.

Comment: @IsaacBennetch No, I have never installed another MySQL server or something like that. In the process list, I have not found a service running like MariaDB or on the port that is used.

Answer (score 0):

In `my.ini` (in XAMPP check `MYSQL`->`Config`) these settings could me modified:

```
# Change here for bind listening
# bind-address="127.0.0.1" 
# bind-address = ::1          # for ipv6
```

By the way, I am running xampp on my local Win and the output is very similar to your `mysql-error.log`, but i did manually install MYSQL server and the just link username/password and hostname to this SQL server instance.